# How to recursively loop through a directory on a specific filetype?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, file-type

I can't find a specific mention of my issue, though it seems like it would be a common problem.

I'm trying to loop through all batch files in a directory, regardless of how deep.

Here is what I have:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('dir %DIR% /s /b *.bat') do (
    if not exist %%a\* echo %%a
)
```

Where DIR is set beforehand. I'm echoing only files.

Clearly this is wrong as it outputs firstly all files, THEN all batch files.

Seems I need to somehow merge the *.bat specifier and the %DIR% variable but I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /r %DIR% %%a in (*.bat) do ( ...
```

Comment: This worked for me. I'm curious to see the reasoning behind the two answers provided - this one seems much simpler. Any contributions on that topic?

Comment: @Rail24 - This method is preferred if the DO does not modify the tree listing, as it is faster and works with unicode in file names. But suppose the DO adds new files, then those newly created files may also be iterated, depending on how they sort and how large the internal buffer is. The FOR /F with DIR /S/B/A-D is needed if the DO modifies or adds files, because it caches the result of the entire listing before it begins to iterate. But FOR /F does not play well with unicode.

Answer (score 1):

You question is somewhat vague to me, but I think this is what you want:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set DIR=h:\scripts

for /f "usebackq delims=;" %%q in (`dir %DIR%\*.bat /s/b/a-d`) do (
    echo %%q
)

endlocal
```

This puts all .bat files into `%%q`.

Comment: The problem here is files with spaces in them. Previously, it seemed like the `delims=` solved that issue. Any idea?

Comment: I added in a delims=; so that spaces are included in the file name